# How to append a clob to a clob at a specific location?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, clob

`v_clob_long clob;
v_clob_short clob;`

I have two clob variables and need to insert v_clob_short right before the 2 last characters of v_clob_long. Is that possible and if so, how?

The issue is that I have a large json object, and need to add a smaller json object as a property to it, however, the json packs that we use don't really allow me to do that.

Oracle version is 11g if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible through use of `substr()` function and applying `to_clob()` function after the concatenation ends :

```
select to_clob
       (  substr(v_clob_long,1,length(t.v_clob_long)-2)||
                 v_clob_short||
          substr(v_clob_long,-2)) 
  from tab
```

assuming those variable names are column names of a table `tab` if each concatenated pieces fitting within `4000` chars length. Otherwise you need to apply `substr(v_clob_col,1,4000)` as much as needed such as

```
select to_clob
       (  substr(v_clob_long,1,4000)||
          substr(substr(v_clob_long,4001,length(t.v_clob_long)-2)||
                 v_clob_short||
          substr(v_clob_long,-2)) 
  from tab
```